# How to fix "Unresolved compilation problems: The type String is not visible" error in VSCode (Java)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am writing a program in Java, and am getting the error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: The type String is not visible."

The program is running in VSCode, with Java 11. The program worked when it was running in eclipse, and when it was running in intellij. This error has occurred for all inputs I have tested (for example, "methane").

scanner class:

```
package setupbiomolecule;
import setupbiomolecule.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerClass {
    public static String understoodMolecules() {
        return "alkane, alkene, alkyne, carboxilic acid, ester, ketone, amine, amide, ether, aldehyde or alcohol. ";
    }
    public static String errorMessage() {
        return "Error! You have either mispelled your molecule, not used standard nomenclature (http://www.chem.uiuc.edu/GenChemReferences/nomenclature_rules.html), or input a molecule that is not an" +  ScannerClass.understoodMolecules() + "Also, it can't have more than 10 carbons";
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String moleculeName = "";
        System.out.println("Enter any "  + understoodMolecules() + "with 10 or fewer carbons. \nIt MUST be in IUPAC standard nomenclature!! \nThis program will tell you the formula! Type 'stop' to stop.");
        while(!moleculeName.equals("stop")) {
            System.out.println("What is your Biomolecule?");
            moleculeName = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
          System.out.println(FunctionalGroupIdentifier.identifyType(moleculeName));
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

part of the functional group identifier:

```
package setupbiomolecule;
import functionalgroups.*;
public class FunctionalGroupIdentifier {
    public static String identifyType(String molecule) {
        String stringToReturn = null;
        if(molecule.endsWith("ane")) {
            stringToReturn = Alkanes.go(molecule);
        }
        return stringToReturn;
    }
}
```

alkane class:

```
package functionalgroups;
import setupbiomolecule.PrefixToCarbon;

public class Alkanes {
    public static String go(String molecule) {

        int carbons = 0;
        int endOfCarbons = molecule.indexOf("ane");
        String carbonPrefix = molecule.substring(0, endOfCarbons);

        carbons = PrefixToCarbon.prefixToCarbon(carbonPrefix);

        int hydrogens = carbons*2+2;
        String formula = "C"+ carbons + "H"+ hydrogens;
        return formula;
    }
}
```

The program is intended to output the formula for the molecule (methane would be CH4).
The error message in full is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
>   The type String is not visible
>   The type String is not visible
>   at functionalgroups.Alkanes.go(Alkanes.java:6) at >setupbiomolecule.FunctionalGroupIdentifier.identifyType(FunctionalGroupIdentifier.java:16)
>   at setupbiomolecule.ScannerClass.main(ScannerClass.java:19)
>   Daniel:biomoleculeApp mirawelner$

Any and all help appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: You have not included your full `FunctionalGroupIdentifier` class. I hope you are returning the `String` `stringToReturn` in the `identifyType` method.

Comment: Also please show the full error stack trace.

Comment: In the package `setupbiomolecules`, you shouldn't import `setupbiomolecules.*` - all the types in the current package are available directly and don't need to be imported. As for your problem, check if you don't have a type or interface named `String` somewhere in your packages.